# jQuery Validation - form bean prepopulated fields

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a form (EDIT functionality) where I prepopulate values and let user update. If user removes a required filed, I need to validate when submitted. Below code is working when the form bean is empty (first time ADD feature) but EDIT feature comes with values in formbean and pre-populates all the form fields. Somehow even if I blank out the filed, when submitting, valid() method returns as true and getting submitted. Can some one help how to handle this ? Thanks!

```js
$("#ProviderPaymentSearchForm").validate({ // initialize the plugin
    npi : {
            required : true,
            number : true               
        }
    },
    messages: { 
        npi : {
            required : "Please Enter an NPI",
            digits: "Please Enter a valid NPI number"
        }
    }
}); // end of Validate  

$("#updateProviderBtn").click(function(e){      
    var val = $("#AmbEditProviderForm").valid();
    if(val){            
        $("#AmbEditProviderForm").submit();
    }
}); // end of click
```

```html
<form:form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" name="AmbEditProviderForm" id="AmbEditProviderForm"
    modelAttribute="ambProviderInfo" action="ambEditProvider.html">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label for="npi">NPI</label>
        <form:input type="text" class="form-control" id="npi" name="npi" placeholder="NPI" path="npi" />
    </div>

    <button type="submit" id="updateProviderBtn" name="updateProviderBtn" class="btn btn-success px-4 float-right">
        Update Provider
    </button>
</form:form>;
```